# Using JavaScript namespacing

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I am trying to convert this code to a namespace to make it cleaner and to avoid polluting the global namespace. I'm fairly new to this, and could use a little guidance or examples how I would convert the following code into a javascript namespace.

```
function Validator(fields) {
     this.fields = fields;
}

Validator.prototype.validate = function(form) {
  for(var i = 0, l=this.fields.length; i < l; i++) {
    alert(this.fields[i].value);
        if (this.fields[i].value == 0) {
            alert("The field  is empty");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

var validator = new Validator([ "username", "password"]);

function runValidate(form) {
validator.validate(form);
    }
```

(I know this OO approach to validation is excessive!) I call this runValidate from a button in a form like this "runValidate(this.form)".

Comment: Is that `runValidate` function really necessary? It saves you only 7 chars.

Comment: Thanks. what should I do instead of it?

Comment: Just directly call `validator.validate(this.form)` from the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces are just javascript objects, for example

```
var myNamespace = {};
myNamespace.Validator = function(fields) {
   ...
}
myNamespace.Validator.prototype.validate = function(form) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should I do the same with my runValidate function? how would I set var validator?

Comment: would var validator = new Validator([ "username", "password"]); become  var validator = new myNamespace.Validator([ "username", "password"]); ?

Comment: Correct, you now call `new myNamespace.Validator` instead of `new Validator`. And then use validator.validate, as @Bergi suggested, I see no point in having `runValidate` function.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have native namespaces but you could use plain and simple objects to simulate that. Here's a simple implementation of a namespace utility function:

```js
function namespace(namespaceString) {
  var nodes = namespaceString.split('.'),
      parent = window,
      currentNode;    

  for(var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {
    currentNode = nodes[i];
    parent[currentNode] = parent[currentNode] || {};
    parent = parent[currentNode];
  }

  return parent;
}
```

You can use like this:

```js
var MyApp = namespace("MyApp");
MyApp.Validator = function(fields) {
  this.fields = fields;
}

var validator = new MyApp.Validator(["username", "password"]);
// this also works:
var validator = new namespace("MyApp.Validator")(["username", "password"]);
```

This will keep you from poluting your global namespace but you will still have some global variables: `MyApp` in this case and any other root node in your namespaces.

Comment: Many thanks. Would the function call from the button in the form remain the same?

Comment: Yes. Even if it's not the best way to go, it should work just fine.